# Doubts in implementing controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting with Ruby on Rails and get'm making an application that takes the likes of a facebook user and transforms them into products, creating a personalized gift list.

Well, I have three models: user, and like product. They are thus:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :product
  attr_accessible :category, :created_time, :name
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :like
  attr_accessible :image_url, :price_max, :price_min, :product_name,
  :url
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products, through: :likes, dependent: :destroy
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :facebook_username, :provider, :uid
end
```

I am also using two gems that help me catch the likes and turn them into products. I have two methods I use in 'rails console' for this:

```
#Facebook Client
client = FBGraph::Client.new(
  client_id: 'client_id',
  secret_id: 'secret_id',
  token: 'token'
  )

#Getting and Recording Likes
like = client.selection.me.likes.info!.data.data
like.sort_by{ |like| like.created_time.to_i }.reverse.each do |like|
    case like.category
      when 'Musician/band' then category = 'band'
     ...
    else next
      Like.create(category: category, created_time: like.created_time, name: like.name, user_id: current_user.id)
    end


#Product API Client
buscape = Buscape.new(
  app_id: 'app_id',
  sandbox: true
  )

#Getting product through likes, and recording
def find_for_products
likes.each do |like|
  case like.category
    when 'band' then
      product = @buscape.products.where(keyword: URI.encode(like.name), categoryId: 2921, results: 1)['product']
    ...
    else next
    end

    Product.create(
      image_url:product['thumbnail']['url'],
      price_max:product['priceMax'],
      price_min:product['priceMin'],
      product_name:product['productName'],
      url:product['links']['link'][0]['url']
      )
  end
end
```

Using the rails console, I can manually register products and likes using Like.new and Product.new, and assign it to a user accessing and using 'user.products', but I have no idea how to **implement it and in my view** and **in my comtroller** to **catch the likes of current_user and produce products** at the moment the user clicks a button **'Find products for me'**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using resources, you can define a new action on `User` in your `routes.rb` file, like this:

```
resources :user do
  member do
    post 'find_products'
  end
end
```

Then implement this action in the controller class.

One option is to put the code you have for querying FB and finding products into a `self` method in the `Product` model, something like `Product.find_and_create_products(user)`. Or alternatively into a separate module in a new file in `lib` directory in your rails app. Then call it from the controller.

If this operation takes a long time, you can later add some additonal code to run it as a delayed job, with something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).